# RapidIO packet filtering in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ip, firewall, rapidio

I was wondering if there is support in Linux Kernel for RapidIO packets filtering, something similar to `iptables`, but based on RapidIO header?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be supported. I found this text that shows how to enable the features within the Linux Kernel:

```
CONFIG_RAPIDIO_DMA_ENGINE:

Say Y here if you want to use DMA Engine frameork for RapidIO data
transfers to/from target RIO devices. RapidIO uses NREAD and
NWRITE (NWRITE_R, SWRITE) requests to transfer data between local
memory and memory on remote target device. You need a DMA controller
capable to perform data transfers to/from RapidIO.

If you are unsure about this, say Y here.

Symbol: RAPIDIO_DMA_ENGINE [=n]
Type : boolean
Prompt: DMA Engine support for RapidIO
Defined at drivers/rapidio/Kconfig:25
Depends on: RAPIDIO [=y]
Location:
-> Bus options (PCI etc.)
-> RapidIO support (RAPIDIO [=y])
Selects: DMADEVICES [=y] && DMA_ENGINE [=y]
```

Additionally on kernel.org the feature RapidIO is discussed [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/menuconfig/arch-x86-Kconfig.html#RAPIDIO) and [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/menuconfig/drivers-rapidio-Kconfig.html).

Finally I found a presentation from 2005 Linux Symposium (Vol. 2 - Ottawa, CA) where there was a presentation titled: [RapidIO for Linux](https://www.kernel.org/doc/mirror/ols2005v2.pdf). In this PDF on page 43 of the PDF (actually page # 35 in the docs) is an abstract from that presentation which discusses RapidIO support.

#### References

- http://lkft.sirrow.info/?p=50
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/mirror/ols2005v2.pdf